# Why does initial UIViewController update for iPad but not iPhone?

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, ipad, uiviewcontroller

My universal iOS7 app works fine except the initial `viewController` for the iPhone does not update with new information. The iPad updates correctly. They both use the same exact code but separate storyboards. Both `viewControllers` are set to "initial". If I close the iPhone app and restart it, it updates correctly. It must be something obvious, but I can't find it. Please help.

Here's the subclassed `UIViewController` for both idioms:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    UIApplication *application = [UIApplication sharedApplication];
    application.applicationIconBadgeNumber = 0;

    self.thoughtLabel.layer.cornerRadius = 6.0f;

    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter]addObserver:self selector:@selector(preferredContentSizeChanged:) name:UIContentSizeCategoryDidChangeNotification object:nil];

    self.canDisplayBannerAds = YES;

    [self performSelector:@selector(retrieveFromParse)];
}

-(UIStatusBarStyle)preferredStatusBarStyle
{
    return UIStatusBarStyleLightContent;
}

- (void)preferredContentSizeChanged:(NSNotification *) notification
{
    self.thoughtLabel.font = [UIFont preferredFontForTextStyle:UIFontTextStyleHeadline];
}
- (void)retrieveFromParse
{
    MBProgressHUD *hud = [MBProgressHUD showHUDAddedTo:self.view animated:YES];
    hud.labelText = @"Loading ...";

    NSCalendar *calendar = [NSCalendar currentCalendar];
    [calendar setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone timeZoneWithAbbreviation:@"GMT"]];
    NSDateComponents *components = [calendar components:(NSYearCalendarUnit | NSMonthCalendarUnit | NSDayCalendarUnit | NSHourCalendarUnit | NSMinuteCalendarUnit) fromDate:[NSDate date]];
    [components setHour:0];
    [components setMinute:0];
    NSDate *startTime = [calendar dateFromComponents:components];
    [components setHour:23];
    [components setMinute:59];
    NSDate *endTime = [calendar dateFromComponents:components];

    PFQuery *query = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"Content"];
    [query whereKey:@"date" greaterThanOrEqualTo:startTime];
    [query whereKey:@"date" lessThanOrEqualTo:endTime];
    NSArray *objects = [query findObjects];

    PFObject *object = [objects objectAtIndex:0];
    self.thought = [object objectForKey:@"thought"];
    self.author = [object objectForKey:@"author"];

    PFFile *image = [object objectForKey:@"image"];
    NSData *imageData = [image getData];
    _image = [UIImage imageWithData:imageData];

        NSString *thoughtFormatted = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@\n\n-- ",_thought];
        _thoughtAndAuthor = [thoughtFormatted stringByAppendingString:_author];
        self.imageView.image = _image;
        UIFont* font = [UIFont preferredFontForTextStyle:UIFontTextStyleHeadline];
        UIColor* textColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:0.175f green:0.458f blue:0.831f alpha:1.0f];
        NSDictionary *attrs = @{NSForegroundColorAttributeName : textColor, NSFontAttributeName : font, NSTextEffectAttributeName: NSTextEffectLetterpressStyle};
        NSAttributedString* attrString = [[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithString:_thoughtAndAuthor attributes:attrs];
        self.thoughtLabel.attributedText = attrString;
        [MBProgressHUD hideHUDForView:self.view animated:YES];
}
```

Comment: "does not update with new information" doesn't look like a well-explained developer question. Do you mind showing us some code?

Comment: Which method do you have this issue with? Is it retrieveFromParse not calling? Can you add NSLog to viewDidLoad and have a look is it called on the iPhone. Can you also replace line [self performSelector:@selector(retrieveFromParse)]; with [self retrieveFromParse];

Comment: Thanks Greg, I'll try that and thanks for the shorter call format. I really just don't understand why it would work on iPad, but not iPhone since it's the same code.

Comment: Are you sure everything is connected correctly in both storyboards?

Comment: I believe so. Everything works in both storyboards. The iPad version updates each day with a new string that displays. The iPhone version will not update unless I shutdown the app and restart it.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that your app is not loading the UIView each time your app becomes active, only when it initially loads.

Add an observer in the viewDidLoad method so you can get updates on initial load and when the app becomes active.

```
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(retrieveFromParse) name:UIApplicationDidBecomeActiveNotification object:nil];
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you should place the code for retrieve data inside viewWillAppear so everytime your views appear it will perform the following.

Comment: Okay, I'll try that although I don't understand why it's different for iPhone and iPad with same code.